# Clone a record, then use its auto increment id for further operations

Tags: sql, postgresql

### Update:

After narrowing down the code it seems that the line

```
INSERT INTO table1 TABLE table1_temp RETURNING id
```

is causing the issue. Any tips what is wrong with this?

---

### Original question:

table1 has many colums (I don't care which) and it has an auto increment primary key (id). This is what I need to do and how I'm trying:

First, I'd like to duplicate a record in table1.

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TEMP TABLE table1_temp ON COMMIT DROP AS
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = <some integer>;

ALTER TABLE table1_temp DROP COLUMN id;

WITH generated_id AS (
  INSERT INTO table1 TABLE table1_temp RETURNING id
)
```

Then, perform an insert to some_table where I need to use the generated id of the copy that was created in table1.

```
INSERT INTO some_table (something, the_id_into_this)
VALUES ('some value', (SELECT id FROM generated_id));
```

Then get some data from yet_another_table (columns: somestuff, id_here) and use this and the id for an insert into that same table.

```
INSERT INTO yet_another_table
  (SELECT somestuff,
  (SELECT id FROM generated_id) AS id_here
  FROM yet_another_table
  WHERE id_here = <some integer>)
```

Finally, I need to return the id so I can use it in my app...

```
RETURNING id_here AS id;
COMMIT;
```

Am I on the right path implementing this? When running the query, I get the following error:

> column "id" is of type integer but expression is of type character
>   varying HINT: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

It doesn't tell me the line number where it occurrs and I have no idea what might cause this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple solution for cloning a record with an auto increment id that doesn't require you to specify any other columns of the table:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TEMP TABLE table1_temp ON COMMIT DROP AS
  SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = #;
UPDATE table1_temp SET id = nextval('table1_seq');
INSERT INTO table1 TABLE table1_temp;
COMMIT;
```

And for the CTE part of the question, here is how you can reuse a returned value at multiple subsequent queries by concatenating WITH statements:

```
WITH generated_id AS (
  INSERT INTO ... RETURNING id
), _ AS (
  QUERY1 ... SELECT id FROM generated_id ...
), __ AS (
  QUERY2 ... SELECT id FROM generated_id ...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table1 TABLE table1_temp
```

You cannot do that because `table1_temp` has different set of columns (you dropped `id` column).
You need to specify columns explicitly (all but `id` column):

```
INSERT INTO table1(col1, col2, ...) TABLE table1_temp
```

Comment: Oh I see, thanks! Do you know any way I could avoid manually specifying the columns in the query? It shouldn't be that hard to let the engine know somehow dynamically without 'hardcoding' which columns to use, after all the list of columns is there in `table1_temp`.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You have to specify all columns if tables don't match.