# Update a numeric column so that the values of its fields build a sequence starting with x

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a table like this:

```
+----+-----
| id | ...
+----+-----
|  4 | foo
|  2 | bar
|  7 | baz
|  5 | gux
|  . | ...
|  . | ...
|  . | ...
|    |
```

I'd like to assign new ids to all records in it so that they build the sequence

`an = an-1 + 1; a0 = x` where I define `x`.

So e.g. with `x` set as `8`, the table would become

```
+----+-----
| id | ...
+----+-----
|  8 | foo
|  9 | bar
| 10 | baz
| 11 | qux
|  . | ...
|  . | ...
|  . | ...
|    |
```

How does the `UPDATE` statement look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Having mutable ids is a very bad design.
2. if x < max(id) you will have problems with duplicated ids and the transaction will fail.

But if you are doing this for a test or a very specific task, and you are aware of the possible problems, you can do it with a sequence:

for example: x = 2000

```
    CREATE SEQUENCE myseq START 2000;
    update mytable set id = nextval('myseq');
```

Obviously you will lose your original id order.

Comment: It's just an abstraction of a problem, an operation I perform on a temporary table when manipulating records of another. An improved version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47994704/5214911) to make the cloning of multiple rows possible.

Answer (score 1):

I can see this being highly unpredictable for other use cases, and I agree with the design comment from @mnesarco.  All that said, here is a solution that will probably do what you described in your question:

```
with baz as (
  select
    id, bar,
    row_number() over (order by 1) as rn,
    max (id) over (partition by 1) as max_id
  from
    foo
)
update foo
set
  id = baz.max_id + baz.rn
from baz
where
  foo.id = baz.id
```

The one real caveat I have is this says "order the rows by nothing" (`order by 1` in the analytic function) which is a real strange thing to do.  Because of the way PostgreSQL does DML with MVCC, a single update will make that row "go to the end" of the table.  Order is never implicit, so unless you specifically tell it why those IDs go in that order, there is no guarantee this will assign the IDs the way you want them.  I would feel much better if there were some column or columns we could implicitly order by -- then I would feel good about this approach for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for raising attention to this ordering anomaly, I didn't think about it!